# A way to change font color besides *.SelectionColor, or a way to better make use of it?

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

So, I'm trying to create a function or two that takes html tags and colors them differently than the rest of the text (similar to how Visual Studio does it for key words like `Dim`). The only way I have found, is to use a rich text box and then do `*.SelectionColor = Color.Blue`, or something similar. Is there any other way to do this? I made it so whenever the textbox updates, it reads through it at changes all html tags to a different color. This works fine with a really short html file, but when they get to be larger, it takes too long, and the selection moves the cursor around.

**So, is there any other way to do this, even if I have to use something other than a rich text box? If not, does anyone see a way to improve this?**

Here are the two functions that run when the textbox updates. Tag is blue, attributes are red, stuff in quotes is green.

```
    '//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    '// findTag()
    '// -finds a tag
    '//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Private Function findTag()
        Dim tag As String = ""
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim startTag As Integer

        While (i < txtCurrentFile.TextLength - 1)
            If txtCurrentFile.Text(i) = "<" Then
                startTag = i
                While txtCurrentFile.Text(i) <> ">"
                    tag += txtCurrentFile.Text(i)
                    i += 1
                End While
                tag += ">"
                colorCode(startTag, tag)
                tag = ""
            End If
            i += 1
        End While
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    '//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    '// colorCode()
    '// -colors different tags accordingly
    '//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Private Function colorCode(ByVal startIndex As Integer,
                               ByVal tag As String)
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim isAttributes As Boolean = False
        Do While (tag(i) <> " " And tag(i) <> ">")
            txtCurrentFile.Select(startIndex + i, 1)
            txtCurrentFile.SelectionColor = Color.Blue
            i += 1
        Loop

        If i < tag.Length Then
            Do Until (tag(i) = ">")
                Do Until (tag(i) = Chr(34))
                    txtCurrentFile.Select(startIndex + i, 1)
                    txtCurrentFile.SelectionColor = Color.Red
                    i += 1
                Loop
                i += 1
                Do Until (tag(i) = Chr(34))
                    txtCurrentFile.Select(startIndex + i, 1)
                    txtCurrentFile.SelectionColor = Color.Purple
                    i += 1
                Loop
                i += 1
            Loop
            txtCurrentFile.Select(startIndex + i, 1)
            txtCurrentFile.SelectionColor = Color.Blue
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

a few suggestions:

1. Ditch the character scanner.  Replace it with anything that is speedier (RegEx, HTML Agility Pack, ...)
2. If you really want to keep the character scanner, then limit the scan to the area around the modifications (say, 200 characters behind and in front of the cursor)
3. Remember where the cursor is before you start the color process and restore it when finished.
4. Implement a background colorizer that does a full file re-color on a separate thread (you'll have to clone the RTB and only apply the changes if the user hasn't made any changes while the colorizer was running).

Comment: See @JohnBustos answer.  It has a better chance of working properly (e.g. The IE team probably did a better job than you or I could ever hope to do of implementing CSS), and requires less coding on your part.

Comment: I really like the idea of number 2. I had a similar idea, just didn't implement it. 3 is a good idea as well. I'm not entirely sure how to use threads in VB yet, but that would make sense, that way you could continue on as it did its thing. Number 1, I haven't the slightest idea about.

Nonetheless, thank you for the suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

... I don't know if this would work AT ALL!!!, but it could be cool if it did...

Maybe open the file in a webbrowser control and set your coloring rules in a css sheet??

Again, I don't know if this is a good idea or not, but it might do the trick very nicely since it's already HTML you're dealing with...

Comment: The web browser would interpret the html like any other page, so would not show you the actual html text, unless you encoded it before handing it to the web browser.  Very good idea.

Comment: Convert to a .txt and then handle it with a webbrowser... that may work. I'm pretty sure IE can open .txt files. Thanks.